# Selecting with two different WHERE statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling to work out how to run a select query where I'm checking for two different values at the same time, and wanting them in seperate columns.

My table example:

```
ID | foreignID | value |  accepted
----------------------------------
 1 |         1 |     5 |         Y
 2 |         1 |     2 |         Y
 3 |         1 |     4 |         N
 4 |         2 |     8 |         Y
```

And what I'm trying to do is along the lines of this:

```
SELECT 
    foreignID, 
    SUM(value WHERE (accepted='Y')) AS sum1,
    SUM(value WHERE (accepted='N')) AS sum2
FROM example
WHERE foreignID='1'
```

My expected results would be:

```
foreignID | sum1 | sum2
------------------------
        1 |    7 |    4
```

Obviously the above code wouldn't work, it's just a half-sudo code to show what I want. Essentially I only want to check with one foreignID but then get results from several SUMs that each require their own argument.

Does anyone know of any ways in which this could be achieved, or something similar. I've tried UNION which puts it into...

```
foreignID | sum
        1 |   7
        1 |   4
```

... but that's not really what I'm after.

I've also seen [multiple select in one sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427757/multiple-select-in-one-sql-statement) which seems to be on the right track but again, that's using UNION which I don't think is ideal for my example.

I could be wrong there so please do prove me wrong if I am. I might just be overlooking something! Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Does postgresql not have `GROUP BY`?

Comment: You are looking for the [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) function

Comment: Using `foreignID='1'` is a bad idea if `foreignID` is an integer/numeric column. `'1'` is character string, `1` is a number. You should always use the correct datatype representation for your constants.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah you're correct on that one. I did notice that at the time of writing and thought it odd but kept it there for consistency's sake, since it's just example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    foreignID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN accepted = 'Y' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS sum1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN accepted = 'N' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS sum2
FROM example
WHERE foreignID='1'
```

Comment: Bang on. I'm a complete idiot for forgetting the CASE function there. Cheers for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is more readable than the `case`:

```
select
    foreignID,
    sum("value" * (accepted = 'Y')::int) sum1,
    sum("value" * (accepted = 'N')::int) sum2
from example
where foreignID = '1'
```

The cast of the boolean to integer results in 0 or 1. Many, if not most, of the languages cast the same way. I tested in four:

C#

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
    7 * Convert.ToInt32(true) - 2 * Convert.ToInt32(false), 
    // Or shorter:
    7 * (true ? 1 : 0) - 2 * (false ? 1 : 0)
);
```

Python

```
>>> 7 * True - 2 * False
7
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(7 * true - 2 * false);
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo 7 * true - 2 * false;
?>
```

Comment: I disagree that this form is more readable.  Fewer characters is often more readable, but not always.  I use so many different languages every day that I can't remember what the rules are regarding boolean casting in all of them (in some it's not even a permitted operation!) that I'd rather spell it out explicitly than have to go look up casting behavior each time.  But if this is more readable to you, then more power to you. :)

Comment: @cdhowie I tested with four of the top languages in your top tags. And I would be surprised if Java behaved differently to C#. That leaves C and C++. How different are those? What main languages you know that don't cast that way? I mean apart from the stupids SQL Server and MySQL?

Comment: Your C# example is not correct -- the `Convert` class is not the same as casting.  `(int)true` in C# is a compile-time error, as the types cannot be casted.  I generally object to any cast regarding a boolean, and prefer instead to write the equivalent of `boolean ? 1 : 0` as it makes my intent clear.  In some systems, particularly older C code, it's not uncommon to have `TRUE` defined as 1, and `FALSE` defined as 2.  Even if it is well-defined in SQL, I consider it a bad idea to treat booleans as integers.  My two cents, not downvoting or anything, that's just my opinion.

Comment: @cdhowie I must have one of the worst memories in the word as I always have to relearn things already mastered before. The very basic C# sample I wrote above took me a few minutes to write although only 3 months ago I finished a solitary 8 months development of a complex asp.net/C# application. Since then I did some different things but not C#. So I understand if you like it the most explicit possible. What I mean is that in this case it is so simple that I prefer the short path. But then again it is up to each one. Your comments are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!10/3aff8/6)

```
create table test(
      id int ,
      foreignid int,
      value int,
      accepted char(1)
      )



    INSERT INTO test values (1,1,5,'Y');
    INSERT INTO test values (2,1,2,'Y');
    INSERT INTO test values (3,1,4,'N');
    INSERT INTO test values (4,2,8,'Y');


    select 
    foreignid,
    sum( case when accepted='Y' then value else 0 end) as sumY
    ,sum( case when accepted='N' then value else 0 end) as sumN
    from test
    group by foreignid;
```