# How to SELECT COUNT multiple values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

rather a newbie at SQL, so please be gentle....as I think this is a basic one.

I'm trying to write a query with multiple (13) counts, based off Column1. The 1st Count is the over-all total. And then the 12 others are filtered by Color. I can get my results by doing multiple Counts all in one query, but this gives me 13 rows of data. The goal here is to get everything on just one row. So, almost like each count would be its own column. Here is an example of the data model

```
Database = CARS, Table = TYPES, Column1 = LICENSE, Column2 = COLOR
```

---

```
SELECT COUNT (LICENSE) AS 'Total ALL Cars'
FROM CARS.TYPES WITH (NOLOCK)

SELECT COUNT (LICENSE) AS 'Total RED Cars'
FROM CARS.TYPES WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE COLOR = 'RED'
```

And on & on & on for each remaining color. This works, but again, I'm trying to streamline it all into one row of data, IF possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple select in one sql statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427757/multiple-select-in-one-sql-statement)

Answer (score 17):

You simply need to include color in select statement and group by it to count cars of each color.

```
 SELECT Color, Count(*)
 FROM CARS.TYPES WITH(NOLOCK)
 GROUP BY Color
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Color = 'RED' THEN 1
                  ELSE NULL
             END) AS RedCars
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Color = 'BLUE' THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS BlueCars
       ,COUNT(*) AS AllCars
    FROM CARS.TYPES WITH ( NOLOCK )
```

Comment: best solution so far, it counts values that are not known beforehand

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with a conditional `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN 1 END) AS 'Total Red Cars'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN 1 END) AS 'Total Blue Cars'
FROM CARS.TYPES
```

If using MySQL you can simplify further:

```
SELECT SUM(Color = 'Red') AS 'Total Red Cars'
      ,SUM(Color = 'Blue') AS 'Total Blue Cars'
FROM CARS.TYPES
```

Comment: You can simplify this with `SUM(Color='Red')`.

Comment: @DanielSparing Depends on database, that would work in MySQL, but not in SQL Server.

Comment: Fair enough, good to know that about SQL Server then, thanks!

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` is SQL Server

Comment: Thx Goat CO. That did it. Now I do have some NULLs on certain colors, is there a way i can remove those from being displayed?

Comment: what do you mean you have NULLs? do you not have value for color or you just don't have any rows?

Comment: Yeah, I had NULLs, trying to count for colors that didn't' exist on a car. Your query example from earlier, showed me how to get around that. Now instead of NULL, it just shows 0 as it should

Comment: @Doctorj77 You can wrap a line in `ISNULL()` to replace `NULL` with `0`, ie:  `ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN 1 END),0)`

Answer (score 4):

Or with `PIVOT`

```
SELECT RED + BLUE + GREEN AS total,
       RED,
       BLUE,
       GREEN
FROM   CARS.TYPES PIVOT (COUNT (LICENSE) FOR COLOR IN ([RED], [BLUE], [GREEN])) P
```

Comment: There is beautiful simplicity here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT SUM(Al) AllCount, SUM(Red) RedCount, SUM(Green) GreenCount, ...
 (  
   SELECT 1 AS Al 
   , CASE WHEN Color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Red 
   , CASE WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Green
   ... 
   FROM CARS.Types
 )
```